# VLOOKUP and INDIRECT, TEXT formula combination

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, vlookup, google-query-language

Here is perfectly working formula I have combines with the help of [Alistair McEvoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13824334/alistair-mcevoy) and [idfurw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16125139/idfurw):

```
=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(A4,IMPORTRANGE("1RnkAkydjc_wY_iLyyfktUucvi9MHmneVTL9H9J3bgss/","08/16!A2:Q26"),6), VLOOKUP(A4,IMPORTRANGE("1RnkAkydjc_wY_iLyyfktUucvi9MHmneVTL9H9J3bgss/","08/16!A2:Q26"),9))
```

However, I want to update it. Especially this part: `"08/16!A2:Q26"` from above formula.

How do I re-write formula so that instead of 08/16 would be value from cell A1. Cell A1 contains 08/16 (date format).

This formula gets me data from different unopened google sheet. Unopened spreadsheet contains sheet named 08/16 where data should be extracted from.

I tried this combination but it did not work:

```
=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(A4,IMPORTRANGE("1RnkAkydjc_wY_iLyyfktUucvi9MHmneVTL9H9J3bgss/",INDIRECT("'"&TEXT($A$1,"MM/dd")&"'!A2:Q26"),6), VLOOKUP(A4,IMPORTRANGE("1RnkAkydjc_wY_iLyyfktUucvi9MHmneVTL9H9J3bgss/",INDIRECT("'"&TEXT($A$1,"MM/dd")&"'!A2:Q26"),9))
```

Probably I am doing mistakes with `'` and `"`

So I want to transform  `"08/16!A2:Q26"` into -->  `"08/16!A2:Q26"` but instead of `08/16` will be value from `A1` cell. `A1` cell value is `08/16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=HYPERLINK(
 VLOOKUP(A4, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1RnkAkydjc_wY_iLyyfktUucvi9MHmneVTL9H9J3bgss/",
 A1&"!A2:Q26"), 6), VLOOKUP(A4,
 IMPORTRANGE("1RnkAkydjc_wY_iLyyfktUucvi9MHmneVTL9H9J3bgss/",
 A1&"!A2:Q26"), 9))
```

or:

```
=HYPERLINK(
 VLOOKUP(A4, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1RnkAkydjc_wY_iLyyfktUucvi9MHmneVTL9H9J3bgss/",
 TO_TEXT(A1)&"!A2:Q26"), 6), VLOOKUP(A4,
 IMPORTRANGE("1RnkAkydjc_wY_iLyyfktUucvi9MHmneVTL9H9J3bgss/",
 TO_TEXT(A1)&"!A2:Q26"), 9))
```

Comment: Thank you! You hinted me to what I need to do
This is final formula : TEXT($A$1,"MM/dd")&"!A2:Q26"